# JS: Deep Searching a value within nesting of objects and array not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I have two functions `findInObj` and `findInArray` that tries to match/find a value for e.g `ldfzjeyfuvbkcjccztn` (needle) within a nesting of objects and arrays (*HAYSTACK*) and *returns* the *PARENT object* OR FALSE, recursively calling itself where appropriate. Somehow the setup dosen't work, though the value is in the *HAYSTACK*.

**HAYSTACK**

```
{
    "slide1":
    {
        "uid": 1672503300574,
        "zones": [
        {
            "imgData":
            {
                "name": "Universe.png",
                "type": "image/png",
            },
            "uid": 1648468065257,
            "styles":
            {
                "height": "327px",
                "width": "421px"
            },
            "canvasElementType": "photo"
        },
        {
            "imgData":
            {
                "name": "water_treatment_plant.png",
                "type": "image/png",
            },
            "uid": 1648468065580,
            "styles":
            {
                "height": "517px",
                "width": "536px"
            },
            "canvasElementType": "photo"
        }],
        "headings": [
        {
            "title": "First TextBox",
            "titleStyles":
            {
                "height": "92px",
                "width": "498px"
            },
            "uid": "ldfzjesz45rh6v5lvoi"
        },
        {
            "title": "Secoooond TextBox",
            "titleStyles":
            {
                "height": "116px",
                "width": "282px"
            },
            "uid": "ldfzjeub9zix7yuajmj"
        },        
        {
            "title": "Infinity",
            "titleStyles":
            {
                "height": "97px",
                "width": "315px"
            },
            "uid": "ldfzjeyfuvbkcjccztn"
        }],
        "slideWrapperStyles": {},
        "duration": 5000,
    }
}
```

**Func - Find In OBJECT**

```
export function findInObj(obj, needle) {
  for(var key in obj) {
      var val = obj[key]
 
    //if ITEM is an Array
    if(val instanceof Array) {
      let retVal = findInArray(val, needle, obj)
      if(retVal) return retVal
    }

    //If ITEM is an Object
    if(val instanceof Object && !(val instanceof Array)) {
      return findInObj(val, needle)
    } else {

    //Neither Object or Array
      if(val == needle) {
          return obj
      }
    }
  }
  //Return `false` when the no item matches
  return false
}
```

**Func - Find In ARRAY**

```
export function findInArray(arr, needle, obj) {
  console.log("arr", arr);
  
  for(var item of arr) {
    
    //if item is an array
    if(item instanceof Array) {
      let retVal = findInArray(item, needle, obj)
      if(retVal) return retVal
    }
    
    //If Item is an Object
    if(item instanceof Object && !(item instanceof Array)) {
      let retVal = findInObj(item, needle)
      if(retVal) return retVal
    }
    
    //If Item is `anything`other than Array/Object
    if(item == needle) {
      return obj
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

I am not able to really pin-point the issue/problem in either of the functions but IMO, in `findInObj` where there is an object that doesn't have either object or Array then the function just returns false and ends there. In other words the properties adjacent/at the same level to the nested object (that doesn't have an object/array) within aren't even checked.

Please help make both these functions work irrespective of at what level the value is.

Comment: Replace this part `return findInObj(val, needle)` with `let retVal = findInObj(item, needle)
      if(retVal) return retVal`

Comment: @Konrad thanks for replying, unfortunately, I did try `if(retVal) return retVal` but then the setup goes into an Infinite loop, (wanted to mention this initially but didn't know how to frame it). FYI, *removed* redundant HAYSTACK data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is on this line `return findInObj(val, needle)` and the line after that, if it goes to that line, if `findInObj(val, needle)` returns `false`, it will return that directly (unlike others that only returns if it's not `false` as checked by `if(retVal) return retVal`). And then the next line after that line is `else` which will not be executed if current item is an object.

This should fix the problem:

```js
const NEEDLE = "ldfzjeyfuvbkcjccztn"
const HAYSTACK = {
  "slide1": {
    "uid": 1672503300574,
    "zones": [{
        "imgData": {
          "name": "Universe.png",
          "type": "image/png",
        },
        "uid": 1648468065257,
        "styles": {
          "height": "327px",
          "width": "421px"
        },
        "canvasElementType": "photo"
      },
      {
        "imgData": {
          "name": "water_treatment_plant.png",
          "type": "image/png",
        },
        "uid": 1648468065580,
        "styles": {
          "height": "517px",
          "width": "536px"
        },
        "canvasElementType": "photo"
      }
    ],
    "headings": [{
        "title": "First TextBox",
        "titleStyles": {
          "height": "92px",
          "width": "498px"
        },
        "uid": "ldfzjesz45rh6v5lvoi"
      },
      {
        "title": "Secoooond TextBox",
        "titleStyles": {
          "height": "116px",
          "width": "282px"
        },
        "uid": "ldfzjeub9zix7yuajmj"
      },
      {
        "title": "Infinity",
        "titleStyles": {
          "height": "97px",
          "width": "315px"
        },
        "uid": "ldfzjeyfuvbkcjccztn"
      }
    ],
    "slideWrapperStyles": {},
    "duration": 5000,
  }
}


function findInObj(obj, needle) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    var val = obj[key]

    //if ITEM is an Array
    if (val instanceof Array) {
      let retVal = findInArray(val, needle, obj)
      if (retVal) return retVal
    }

    //If ITEM is an Object
    if (val instanceof Object && !(val instanceof Array)) {
      let retVal = findInObj(val, needle)
      if (retVal) return retVal
    }

    //Neither Object or Array
    if (val == needle) {
      return obj
    }
  }

  //Return `false` when the no item matches
  return false
}

function findInArray(arr, needle, obj) {
  for (var item of arr) {

    //if item is an array
    if (item instanceof Array) {
      let retVal = findInArray(item, needle, obj)
      if (retVal) return retVal
    }

    //If Item is an Object
    if (item instanceof Object && !(item instanceof Array)) {
      let retVal = findInObj(item, needle)
      if (retVal) return retVal
    }

    //If Item is `anything`other than Array/Object
    if (item == needle) {
      return obj
    }
  }

  //Return `false` when the no item matches
  return false
}

console.log(findInObj(HAYSTACK, NEEDLE))
```